# Sort Order Using Group Total (SSRS)

Tags: sorting, reporting-services

I am trying to sort my results by a sub-total. This sub-total was not received from a SQL count, but rather from using the Group Feature to create the stepped report. I've attached an image of what my results look like. In that image, you can see that it's currently ordered/sorted by the Client Number, and then the matter number (which you can't see but isn't really important at this time).

What I want is for it to list the Client's with the most matters first - that's the sub-total. In the image you can see there is one that has 6, so that should come first. The end sort would be Highest Count -> Client Number -> Matter Number.

Any guidance someone can give me would be great. I was trying to figure out how to do the count from the SQL side, but I don't seem to see a way to do a sub-total count of how many matters each client has. I can only count each matter individually, and do a grand total of how many matters were there, total.

[image]

Comment: You can set a custom sort order on the `Client code` row group. Set it before the Client code (A-Z) and set it to sort Z-A with the expression you use in the `Matter code` column.

Comment: Nicky, you are a GENIUS!!! Thank you thank thank you so much!!!

Comment: Haha, no problem @T. Meyer